# bootstrap modal is not displaying as per my requirement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my bootstrap modal is appearing blue line at the top and bottom of the modal. I didn't know why the blue line is appearing at the top and bottom of the modal. I want to remove the blue line. I am weak in English please apologize me if I made any grammatical or spelling mistakes.

HTML CODE:

```
  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm vcenter" id="deleteconfirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Are you sure you want to Delete it?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
        <h6>By clicking on Yes button your ad will be Delete.</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sayyes">Yes</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.vcenter{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

IMAGE:
[image: look of my modal]

Answer (score 1):

Just add this style `style="outline: none !important"` to your main div.

`<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm vcenter" id="deleteconfirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" style="outline: none !important">`

The blue lines will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are over ridding some styles,

```
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Modal Example</h3>   
        <div>
            <a href="#myModal1" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>
        </div>       
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/h3WDq/1715/)**